# How to terminate the module runned with require.run() in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a game for WP8.1. I use gameJS library which uses some kind of require.js. The html page with the game canvas contains the following code:

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/game/game.html", {

    ready: function (element, options) {
        require.setModuleRoot('/js/');
        require.run('main');            
    }
});
```

The main.js file contains the main game loop and all other game stuff. So, when I first navigate to game.html, then everything works fine. But if I go away from game.html and then go to this page again (for example using back button) I can see only white screen.

I can see in debugger that the main.js runs again and seems like it causes this trouble. Two game loops just collide each other. How to completely terminate and unload main.js when user goes away from game.html?

Comment: There is no `setModuleRoot` call in RequireJS. What you seem to be using is something called [Inject](http://www.injectjs.com/docs/0.7.x/api/inject.setmoduleroot.html). I did not find a tag specifically for this tool. (There is a tag named `inject` but it is about the general *principle* of dependency injection.)

Comment: @Louis, So is there a way to kill the module runned by this Inject?

Comment: I don't know. I was merely commenting to make sure you knew why I edited away the [tag:requirejs] tag.